# Django to_representation and filter_fields err: TypeError: 'Meta.fields'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

**Objective: TO BE ABLE TO ADD _id property to filter_fields**

i'm trying to store the **value** of a property called title in a property called _id which would be the same input as title, just lower case and with no spaces, simple replace() but I've tried instantiating it to_representation().

When I try to add _id to my filter_fields I get the err below, remove it and it runs, but i need to the property _id

```
filter_fields = ('title', '_id',) <--- the _id cause the err
```

```
TypeError: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: _id
```

**models.py**

```py
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**serializer.py** here is where I try to instantiate it by overriding **to_representation()**

```py
class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ('created_at', 'title', 'description', 'link', 'img', )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['_id'] = instance.title.lower().replace(" ", "_")
        return data
```

**api.py**

```py
class PortfolioList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PortfolioSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('title', '_id',)
```

Comment: What is **`_id`** here?

Comment: _id would be the same input as title, just lower case and with no spaces, so title is Hello World, the _id would be > "hello_world"

Comment: The filtering process is carried out in the ORM/DB level. You have to ***annotate*** the queryset before the filtering process. For that, override the **`get_queryset()`** method of your view class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your queryset since `_id` is not a part of the model. You should only annotate when you receive `_id` field in the `query_params`

Better solution would be to implement a custom filter backend.

```
    class PortfolioCustomFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

        def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
            _id = self.request.query_params.get('_id', None)
            if _id is not None:
                title = _id.replace('_', ' ')
                queryset = queryset.filter(title__iexact=title)
            return queryset
```

Comment: thanks i'm pretty new to Django though, would this go in my models, serializer, or api ?

Comment: This should be in your Views (PortfolioList). Add the custom filter class in your ```filter_backends```  tuple.

Comment: i'm getting this for the request argument in the filter_query method 'PortfolioCustomFilterBackend' object has no attribute 'request'
Any clue?